# Value of $a$ such that the equation has integral roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $(a+b+c)x^2+2(a-b)x +a+b-8=0$ has integral roots and $a,b,c \in R^+ ,c>b-3a>0$,then the value of $a$ is ----

I am aware that a condition for integral roots is that the discriminant must be a perfect square but I couldn't deduce anything from it.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Rational root theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: See here: https://www.quora.com/If-a+b+c-x-2-+-2-a-b-x-+-a+b-8-0-has-integral-roots-and-a-b-c-belong-to-+ve-real-and-c-gt-b-3a-gt-0-what-is-the-value-of-a

Comment: The question is not wrong as claimed in the link provided by @Rohan I found hundreds of results, but no way to find "the value of $a$". $a$ can be anything in my results

Comment: @Raffaele kindly share your thoughts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite as 
$$\tag1 x^2+px+q = 0$$
with $$ p=\frac{2(a-b)}{a+b+c},\qquad q=\frac{a+b-8}{a+b+c}.$$
As $p$ is the negative sum and $q$ is the product of the roots (Vieta), both must be integers.

From the given inequality, 
$$-p=\frac{(a+b)+(b-3a)}{a+b+c}\begin{cases}<\frac{a+b+c}{a+b+c}=1\\
>\frac{a+b}{a+b+c}>0 \end{cases}.$$
But there is no such integer.